# Bypass on_command_error(ctx) and call variable of other function

Tags: python, discord.py

In my case I want, that the messages of the ping command are deletet after a cooldown (5s) but the messages of the invite command should be not deleted. Is there a way to bypass the on_command_function without aborting the whole script or is it just easier to delete the messages locally?
And my other question: Is there a way to call the tmp variable, that was created in the ping command, in the on_command_completion function?

Here is a snippet:

```
@commands.command()
async def ping(self, ctx):
    tmp = await ctx.send("Pong")

@commands.command()
async def invite(self, ctx):
    invite = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    tmp = await ctx.send(invite)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_completion(ctx):
    await tmp.delete(delay=5.0)
    await ctx.message.delete(delay=5.0)
```

Comment: Why are you not using the kwarg `await ctx.send("Pong", delete_after=5)`?

Comment: @Dominik I didn't know that. Thanks